# What does the MC_ prefix come from in AKS?

Tags: kubernetes

When creating a cluster in AKS, by default 2 resource groups are created. One of those has a prefix of `MC_` and, as per [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#why-are-two-resource-groups-created-with-aks), is "*known as the node resource group, contains all of the infrastructure resources associated with the cluster. These resources include the Kubernetes node VMs, virtual networking, and storage. By default, the node resource group has a name like MC_myResourceGroup_myAKSCluster_eastus*".

Does anyone know if the `MC` prefix stands for something, or it's just 2 random letters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MC prefix stands for Managed Cluster

Comment: Do you happen to have a source for this?

Comment: You can also provide your own name, as described here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq

If you use an Azure Resource Manager template to deploy an AKS cluster, you can define the resource group name by using the nodeResourceGroup property.

An example here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/2019-06-01/managedclusters?tabs=json

{
  "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters",


As you see the type of resource is specified in the type key: Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters

Hence, Managed Cluster, MC